# In October CMS, How to redirect from a plugin to a page with data

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I'm creating a plugin for October CMS that has a frontend form (component) with

```
{{ form_open({ request: 'onSubmitForm' }) }}
```

In the plugin there is a function `onSubmitForm()` with a `validator`.
If the validator fails I want to redirect to the page the form input came from (`$this->page->url`) but send the validator messages (`$validator->messages()`) and the original input of the form (`post()`) with it.

I've tried:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
  return Redirect::to($this->page->url)->withErrors($validator->messages())->withInput(post());
}
```

and if I put `{{ errors }}` on the page i do get a message

> Object of class Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag could not be converted
>   to string

which I then fixed by using:

```
{% for error in errors.all() %}
  <li>{{ error }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

and `{{ errors.first('name') }}`

but the `{{ input }}` doesn't even return an error.

Am I doing the redirecting wrong? Or does it have to do with how Twig and Blade are so completely different? Is there a way to prefill old input values and error messages?

Answer (score 4):

You can output the old input value with this twig

```
{{form_value('my_input_name')}}
```

[october cms form doc](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/html)

As you can read in the very top you can "translate" php exemple to twig by changing "method name" to lower case and "::" to _

exemple:

```
// PHP
<?= Form::open(..) ?>

// Twig
{{ form_open(...) }}
```

hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

this is my regular code for blade

```
 @if (count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <strong>{{trans('messages.sorry')}}</strong>
                 <br><br>
                 <ul>
                      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                          <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                      @endforeach
                 </ul>
            </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work in Twig... I hate how October CMS didn't incorporate Blade but Twig as their template engine of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting to the same page where the form was submitted from, just use Ajax! You can do in couple ways.

instead of form_open, use form_ajax. 
Here is an example:

```
form_ajax('onSubmitForm', { model: user, class: 'whateverclass', id: 'idoftheform', success:'doSomethingInJS(textStatus, data)'})
```

in PHP, you can return your error message as

```
 return ["ErrorMsg" => 'this is some error']
```

Then in JS you can display it:

```
function whateverClass (textStatus, data){
alert (data.ErrorMsg);
$('#alertHolderDiv').html(data.ErrorMsg);
}
```

another way would be to use a partial! And once you throw an error you can use "update" in ajax command to update the partial. The partial will be overwritten with the new message.